# What is %f in the for loop command?

Tags: windows, batch-file, batch-rename

From this example right here.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/for#additional-references

`for %f in (*.doc *.txt) do type %f`

> In the preceding example, each file that has the .doc or .txt extension in the current directory is substituted for the %f variable until the contents of every file are displayed. To use this command in a batch file, replace every occurrence of %f with %%f. Otherwise, the variable is ignored and an error message is displayed.

Are these different from variables in this example?

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/batch_script/batch_script_variables.htm

```
set message=Hello World 
echo %message%
```

What are these called? How do I manipulate them?

Comment: `%var%` is an "environment variable". It's valid anywhere ("global") until you explicitly destroy it (by undefining it or by `endlocal`, if it was defined after a `setlocal`). `%f` is a "for-variable" or "loop-variable" (I also heard the term "Metavariable"). It's valid only within the `for` loop and has no meaning after the `for` loop ends. Environment variables are manipulated with the `set` command (see `set /?`), for for-variables, there are "modifiers" (see `for /?`)

Comment: @Stephan How does the for variable work though? Is there a difference between %f and %g? Is it something I can manipulate? Is there a page that I can read more on?

Comment: well, there is `for /?`, but you can also visit [SS64](https://ss64.com/nt/) (look for the three links that start with `FOR`). It's better readable and even a bit more descriptive. You can roughly compare it with the runtime variables in other languages (`for $x = 1 to 5 do`). EDIT: Npocmakas answer summarizes it very well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

in batch scripting slang it is called `for loop token` and the example above will work only in the command prompt. For a batch file you'll need double `%`.

These tokens changes their values on each iteration of the for loop. Example (this can be executed in the command prompt):

```
for %a in (1 2) do @echo %a
```

this will have two iterations - in the first the value if the `%%a` token it will be 1 and on the seconds 2.

You can use for loops to read files (with /f switch and no quotes) ,to iterate files (with no switch) or directories (with /d switch), iterate through strings (again without switch but using wild cards in strings is not possible) to read files (with /f and no quotes), or process a string (again with /f).

you can also split the value of each iteration with "delims" option and then you'll need more consecutive letters :

```
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=-" %a in ("1-2-3") do @echo %a:%b
```

this will split the string in the quotes by `-` and will take the first and the second part accessible by the `%a` and `%b` tokens.

More on for loops:

https://ss64.com/nt/for.html

https://ss64.com/nt/for2.html

https://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html

https://ss64.com/nt/for_d.html

https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html

https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html